# Entity Framework Does Not Update Model From Database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have `windows forms project` which uses `entity framework 4.0` with already `generated pocos and model` from database. When I click `Update Model From Database` it asks me for `data connection`. When I click `next` it tells me to `choose between entity framework 5.0 and 6.x` with `notification message` that says *"Your project references an older version of Entity Framework. To use the latest version, exit this wizard and upgrade before performing this action"*
When I click finish after I choose new table it tells me

*An exception of type ‘System.runtime.interopServices.COMException’ occurred while attempting to update from the database. The exception message is: ‘A file or folder with the name ‘Model.Context.tt’ already exists. Please give a unique name to the item you are adding or delete the existing item first*

All I want is to `update the model` with new column on specific poco. I `do not want to update` the entity framework to newer version. What is the problem here ?

Comment: revamp your entity framework, drop your edmx and regenerate again :)

Comment: Probably you created the model with a previous version of Visual Studio (Maybe VS2012) and now you are trying to update the model with VS2015. You have to open the project with that version of VS and update the project. Otherwise you will have to do that @Desperado says.